# HTML is there a limit for numbers of characters inside a comment <!-- -->

Tags: html

In HTML, Is there a limit for numbers of characters inside a comment `<!-- -->` ?
I'm having trouble with files change log. Exceeding 3050 characters inside `<!-- -->` I got errors.
In my case login errors: `the code don't recognize the logged user because of this control` is just after the comment lines.

To well explain this are the lines under comment

```
<!-- 
GESTIONE MAGAZZINO V 2.1.3 

Descrizione:        Inserimento componenti. Carico/scarico componenti.
                    Allocazione/visualizzazione ubicazione componenti

Autore:             Massimo Di Natale
Data creazione :    17/07/2019

Ultima Versione :   2.1.3
Data:               06/03/2021

Change Log
    
    Versione:       2.1.2   28/02/2021
                            Inserito fornitore  
    
    Versione:       2.1.1   31/12/2020
                            Inserito unità di misura    
    
    Versione:       2.1     10/10/2020
                            Crea la prima parte (univoca) del nuovo codice trasformando l'id in un numero esadecimale a 4 cifre 
                            ed aggiunge il trattino dopo le stesse      
    
    Versione:       2.0     24/04/2020
                            Velocizzato il CRUD creando 4 pagine singole. Ogni pagina si apre
                            alla pressione del relativo pulsante (-; +; edit; delete)
                            
    Versione:       1.1.2   05/04/2020
                            Inserito pop up che ricorda di scaricare ghiaccioli quando si spediscono i 
                            Geizeer
    
    Versione:       1.1.1   22/02/2020
                            Inserito descrizione sulla registrazione dei movimenti
    
    Versione:       1.1     30/11/2019
                            Inserito ricerca singolo campo
                            
    Versione:       1.0.4   24/11/2019
                            Inserito controllo accesso
                            Inserito Codice Fornitore su più lineee
                            
    Versione:       1.0.3   11/09/2019
                            Inserito Codice Fornitore e cambiato Categoria in Package

    Versione:       1.0.2   17/07/2019 (VB.net)
                            Ricerca ordinata per ID
                            Inserito ricerca su Tutti i Campi o su Campo singolo

    Versione:       1.0     10/07/2019 (VB.net)
                            Verificato che non sia possibile inserire codici duplicati

    Versione:       0.9     09/07/2019 (VB.net)
                            Inserito funzioni Carica/Scarica q.tà articolo

    Versione:       0.8     08/07/2019 (VB.net)
                            Inserito funzione STAMPA
                            Inserito ordinamento per Id prima dell'inserimento di un nuovo articolo
                            Sistemato tasto ANNULLA GroupBox1

    Versione:       0.7     05/07/2019 (VB.net)
                            Sistemato funzione MODIFICA
                            Private Sub Salva() inserito variabile Inserito/Cancellato su MsgBox

    Versione:       0.6     29/06/2019 (VB.net)
                            Disabilitato bottoni dopo la pressione di uno di essi
                            Ricerca all'interno dei campi
                            Eliminato ricerca su ID

    Versione:       0.5     15/06/2019 (VB.net)
                            Base
                            
    Da fare:                
                            
-->

<?php include 'menu.html'; ?>
```

This are the first lines under menu.html

```
<?php ob_start();
include 'include/controller.php';
$session_username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$session_nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
$session_cognome = $_SESSION['cognome'];
$session_sesso = $_SESSION['sesso'];
$session_livello = $_SESSION['livello'];
$session_posizione =$_SESSION['posizione'];
$login_session = $_SESSION['nome'] ." ". $_SESSION['cognome']; 
if(empty($_SESSION['user_name'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}

//estrae il valore della posizione-livello passata: true se è 1 (attivo),    false se è 0
function user_livelli_valore($posizione){
    $char=$_SESSION['livello'][$posizione-1];
    return $char;
}
?>
```

this are the errors I got if I add other change log versions (more lines at the top)
[image]

**SOLVED**

**Problem was that comments lines were out of < html > tag**

Answer (score 2):

No, HTML does not have any such limit on number of characters.
Below is the example with 13,000 characters inside a comment.

```
   // Please ignore this code block. StackOverflow wants to add a code block before plnkr link.
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/G1vlLqH9j4K6MzLR?preview

Your problem is not well explained in terms of code, if possible please provide an example of code.

Comment: looks like your php code has failed to start. It has not loaded php on page.

Comment: I had no problems until I did a little modification to the code, just a string split on an echo. All works as always until I add new comments, that cause the error messages